# Operator or Helm chart for MongoDB replicas

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

What is the pro/cons of using an operator (like https://github.com/kbst/mongodb) to manage mongodb inside k8s over using Helm chart (like https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb-replicaset) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator you linked to does *not* appear to be very useful (or well documented), so please consider my answer a more general one...

Technically speaking all a Helm chart can do is use existing Kubernetes primitives, e.g., StatefulSet, Service, Deployment, and so forth.
But sometimes we need more custom/specialized tools that are more aware of specifically what they control and are responsible to run.
So for example, a MySQL operator might make it easier to take (reliable) backups or reliably restore the DB from those backups -- something specific to MySQL that Kubernetes doesn't (and shouldn't) know anything about.
Another example would be scaling-up; some distributed systems require steps beyond just running a new container in order for that container to join an existing cluster.
The operator can take care of that, whereas Helm/Tiller provide no such tools (and are not meant/designed to).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what (more or less I understood), but why is their a helm chart for mongodb replicas then ? (cf. https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb-replicaset) Do we have the choice to implement specific DB scaling using Helm OR an Operator ?

Comment: A couple of reasons: first, operators are a newer concepts, and Helm charts predate them. Second, they're not mutually exclusive: an operator is usually installed using a Helm chart, and can install things using a Helm chart. You can scale either the Helm chart or using the operator, the question is how do you then add the new replica(s) to the cluster, and that's specific to MongoDB (which I don't know much about), and that's exactly what operators do that Helm charts don't/can't. Hope this helps!